# Two children with the same elements in react. When I try to delete either of the divs, it deletes both

Tags: reactjs

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `function
>   toString() { [native code] }function toString() { [native code]  Keys
>   should be unique so that components maintain their identity across
>   updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or
>   omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future
>   version.

Here is where my components are instantiated in the component JSX file. It seems that each component instance has the same ID.:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from "react";

import "../../styles/workoutList.css";

const WorkoutList = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="workout-list">{children}</div>
);

export default WorkoutList;
```

The problem arises when I try to delete one of the components, then I get the above error, and all the components are deleted.

Update:

This is a screenshot of the d[Screenshot of web app divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2cfJ.png)

When I press the delete button on the right of either div, both divs get deleted instead of 1.

Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/nditanaka/workout_app_react

Any suggestions?

Comment: What divs? What are the children? You will need to provide actionable information to receive help.

Comment: I've amended the question to show the divs on the page.

Comment: The repo you posted has nothing other than the initial Create React App project. You'll need to commit and push your code changes otherwise there's no point in having it linked here. Although I think it's better to put a working demo of the issue in a stackblitz or the like instead. Since github repos have a tendency to change over time.

Comment: Sorry about that, hadn't added changes before I pushed to remote. I've updated the repo with changes. I'm trying to add the project to stackblitz so it is easier to view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use unique keys when mapping and creating elements. React uses the keys to identify which element is which. So elements with the same key are treated by react as being the same element.

If you don't have a unique key to give them, at least give them the index even though that won't be as performant as having an actual unique key to give them.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

From the error message you have in your post, it looks like you were trying to use a function as the key, which definitely won't work as it will try to serialize that function into a string and those will end up being the same even if they close over different values.